Что за параметры в ffmpeg
Не силен в видео файлах, хотел бы услышать обозначения параметров другими словами нежели в доках.
-b:v:2 800k  -maxrate:2 856k  -bufsize:2 1200k

-b:v:2 800k // Указываем битрейт видео, он же будет фиксированным даже если у входного файла будет ниже. То есть если входной файл 10мб, а битрейт его 450к, на выходе получим 20м с битрейтом 800k. Верно?
-maxrate:2 856k // Что это за рейты, для чего? C ним так же как и с первым, или все же ограничивает, а не приводит строго к 850k?
-bufsize:2 1200k //Совсем не понятно, что это у видео и для чего?

По порядку.

-b:v:2 800k -maxrate:2 856k -minrate:2 756k -bufsize:2 1200k

-b:v:2 - указать усреднённый (average) битрейт для видеопотока 2 (Видеофайлы могут содержать несколько видеопотоков).
-b:v:2 800k - усреднённый битрейт для видеопотока 2, т.е. если входной файл будет иметь "скачки" (к примеру от 450 до 1200) по битрейту во втором видеопотоке, ffmpeg попытается их сгладить и привести общий битрейт видео к примерно к 800 кб/с.
-maxrate:2 856k - жёстко зафиксировать верхнюю границу битрейта для видеопотока 2 в 856 кб/с. Говорим ffmpeg, что выше этого битрейта прыгать нельзя.
-minrate:2 756k - жёстко зафиксировать нижнюю границу битрейта для видеопотока 2 в 756 кб/с. Говорим ffmpeg, что ниже этого битрейта прыгать нельзя.
-bufsize:2 1200k - это опция задаёт: как часто ffmpeg должен вычислять средний битрейт для видеопотока 2.
С bufsize нужно аккуратно поиграться и посмотреть, какой результат вам больше подойдёт. Если вы установите слишком маленький буфер, то это может повлиять на качество выходного видео, так как ffmpeg будет очень часто пытаться вычислить "не вышел ли я за лимиты усреднённого битрейта -b:v". Если установить bufsize большой, то вычисление усреднённого битрейта будет редким, из-за чего могут быть резкие перепады по битрейту к примеру вы хотите разброс в 10кб/с, а при большом bufsize может быть в 100кб/с.
Битрейт так или иначе должен прыгать, в разумных пределах, в зависимости от динамичности сцен. Многие параметры и оптимизации уже сделаны за вас. Вы можете поиграться с параметрами и добиться более подходящего под ваши цели результата, но вам придётся самостоятельно найти эти значения. Почему так происходит? Потому что многие оптимизации сделаны на основе общих ограничений, меняя тот же buffsize вы задаёте другие ограничения для ffmpeg и иногда эти оптимизации перестают работать.

Спс. Понял что, необходимости в среднем битрейте нет. -maxrate это единственный параметр который играет роль. На случай завышенного битрейта, ограничить его. А приводить к среднему, только вес файла будет завышен, а качество лучше не станет. Если у входного файла он будит занижен.

800к ffmpeg смотрит на вес одного кадра? А в секунду их  может быть 30,60 и боллее

кб/с, не один кадр

не забудьте только вместе с maxrate выставить buffsize, а то там по дефолту может быть и 100М

Дайте пожалуйста комментарий еще по данным параметрам -r 25 -keyint_min 250 -g 250 -sc_threshold 0. В команде прописан, которая преобразовывает по технологии dash

Будет довольно трудно объяснить в комментариях.
-r 25 - задаёте фреймрейт в 25 кадров в секунду.

keyint, g, sc_threshold относится к концепции GOP - Group of Pictures. Если кратко: Есть один главный кадр и от него другие кадры строятся по некоторым дельтам (разнице в кадрах).

Концепция GOP на пальцах (надеюсь меня профи не побьют за такое объяснение): Допустим вы снимаете природу и в кадре у вас 5 секунд один цветок, который чуть-чуть меняет положение из-за ветра. Весь фон статичен. Кодек берёт 1 кадр как главный, а в остальные кадры "рисует" только область, где цветок меняет положение, так как фон статичен, его перерисовывать не нужно. Таким образом получается избавиться от информации полных кадров и хранить только их изменения.

Вот -g (-keyint тот же параметр) задаёт размер GOP т.е. допустим у вас 30 кадров, и вы задали -keyint 30, это означает, что в одной такой группе кадров должно быть максимум 30 абстрактных единиц (1 кадр и 29 дельт на него)

sc_threshold 0 это параметр no_scenecut - ffmpeg пытается определить был ли scenecut (смена сцены, например когда вы сменили ракурс). Этими параметрами вы выключаете этот детект.

Важно понимать, что эти параметры специфичны для кодека. Они все используются в h264, но h265 работает по другому и некоторые параметры может игноировать

Информация:
GOP: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24680/what-is-keyint-and-min-keyint-and-no-scenecut
DASH: https://superuser.com/questions/908280/what-is-the-correct-way-to-fix-keyframes-in-ffmpeg-for-dash
Общая информация: https://videoblerg.wordpress.com/2017/11/10/ffmpeg-and-how-to-use-it-wrong/
Шпаргалка по параметрам: https://gist.github.com/tayvano/6e2d456a9897f55025e25035478a3a50
